Do i need ios 17.0 if i have 17.5 simulator runtime?
I’ve got a bit of a situation. Due to a slow internet connection, I asked a friend to download the "iOS 17.5 Release Candidate Simulator Runtime" from the Apple Developer website for me. However, when I open Xcode 15.0, it’s still asking me to download iOS 17.0.



Is it necessary to install iOS 17.0 even though I already have the 17.5 runtime? Or am I missing something?
Should i download ios 17.0 simulator from the Apple developer website too?

Are you able to pick and use the 17.5 sim for running stuff?  If so you don’t need to get the 17.0 sim pack.

@WarrenBurton No, suddenly it’s asking to download ios 17.0, to add any new sim above 16.4. Idk why this happened

@Sweeper as I mentioned in the above comment, i just want to create a sim with the ios 17.5

Well then you don't need 17.0 runtime. You should be able to just add 17.5 simulators in the devices and simulators window (command shift 2).

@Sweeper Yeah that's what I expected, but for some reason, I can’t… Need me to install iOS 17... is there any workaround to handle this without downloading anything?

I will edit the Question and put a screenshot, I have Xcode 14. x, downloaded Xcode 15 then put the iOS 17.5 & 16.4 simulators in the Xcode files

@Sweeper check, please

Can you click "Manage Run Destinations" and add a 17.5 simulator in that window?

@Sweeper In the OS version just 16.4 appears “I added a screenshot”, and although I can't build the project with the 16.4 sim. :/

@AnasTe Well an iPhone 8 can't run iOS 17 in the first place. Try selecting a newer phone model.

@Sweeper AH, sorry, i can select iOS 17.5, but still get the same issue as you see in the second screenshot.

@Sweeper may i ask, if i have xcode15.4, where can i find the iOS SDKs in the Xcode files, maybe If I can copy/paste things will work?

Have you managed to add simulator with iOS 17.5? iPhone 15 for example. May be you need relaunch Xcode to make device list refresh

@Cy-4AH Yeah I can, but I can not build the app, because it needs me to have an iOS 17.0 “second screenshot”. I'm restarting Xcode/laptop but the same issue still exists

I got it. You are missing platform support. Look for it in the Settings -> Components.
